# I want to make my gsuit non admin account into noreply account

Tags: email, gmail, message, google-workspace, replay

I am gsuit user, I have created many user accounts from my admin account of gsuit, i want to make one of the user account as a no-reply account,
i.e. when someone sends reply on that account it should automatically get rejected with reject message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. From your G Suite account go to  Apps > G Suite > Gmail > Advanced Settings.
2. Choose the organizational unit to affect, I would recommend to have this users specifically on an organizational unit since by making this change it will affect all of the users within that OU.
3. After selecting the OU look for the option "Routing" within that option there is another one called the same "Routing"
4. Click on the "Configure" button.

[image: Routing Section from G Suite > Apps > Gmail > Advanced Settings > Routing]

A popup will appear

5. For "Messages to affect" select "Inbound"
6. For "For the above types of messages, do the following" select "Reject message"

[image: Routing Settings]

Comment: You have to enter a required description at the top and you can customize the rejection message at the bottom.

Comment: a pleasure, please consider accept it as an asnwer if that was helpful.

Comment: I am still receiving some emails in my noreply account, having more that 4 cc email Ids

Answer (score 0):

In **Google Admin** (formerly Google Suite) navigate to:

> Apps > Google Workspace > Settings for Gmail > Default Routing

Link: https://admin.google.com/ac/apps/gmail/defaultrouting

- Add a new rule
- (1.) Enter email address: no-reply@domain.com
- (2.) Change "Accept message" to "Decline message"
- (2.) You can optionally enter a decline message
- (3.) Change to "Execute this action for recognized and unrecognized addresses"
- Send a test e-mail to this address to see if it works
- You should receive a reply *Delivery Status Notification (Failure)* after a few minutes