# Email does not accept replies SMTP C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp, smtpclient

I send an email via `SMTP` google and my code is working fine. What I want is to set **this email does not accept replies** in the SMTP setting.

**Working Code**

```
public ActionResult SendEmail()
{
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com", "From Name");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("to@gmail.com", "To Name");
    const string fromPassword = "password";
    const string subject = "Subject";
    const string body = "<p>Hello</p>";

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };
    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = true
        })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Google Mailbox**

[image]

I don't want the `Reply button highlighted in blue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, it is not possible through SMTP to disable a client's reply function.

Instead, you could create a no-reply address with a vacation responder to alert individuals that the inbox is not being monitored (possibly including where to go if a user does need to reach out to someone).

Comment: How can I create a no-reply address and where to set the vacation responder?

Comment: [No Reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954520/9116267).  Looks like you can also set a decline message here as well.
If you are not using Google Admin, then just add a vacation reply to your current sending account (or create a new one to send from). [Here is the link for vacation response](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/25922?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)